# How to include "Add a New contact" in Jquery UI Autocomplete Widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete Widget in my project for find all customer names.

how do i include "Add a new Name" text link inside Autocomplete Widget <LI>?

kindly provide me the solutions.

Comment: [What have ***YOU*** tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) - SO is not a code-writing service, we don't *just provide* solutions - we help when you **show some effort of your own** and when you're stuck somewhere....

Comment: @marc_s i'm using jquery UI automcomplete [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in my projects. i want to add "Add a new Name" text link as a last search results in all search scenario or i need to add text link to append all search list li as last. kindly let me know if you are not getting my answer.

Comment: -1 for "kindly provide me the solutions."? I agree with @marc_s. In future, please make some sort of effort. This was a very poor question IMO.

Comment: @Dom sure. i will do it Dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps...

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"],
    response: function (event, ui) {
        ui.content.push({
            label: 'Add a new Name',
            value: 'Add a new Name'
        });
    },
    open: function (event, ui) { //Add href & class
         $(".ui-autocomplete").find("a").last().attr('href','http://www.google.com').addClass('highLight');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qakct/)**

Comment: great.. thanks for spending time for my solutions. it's working for me.. you saved my time..

Comment: how do i add href & class for "Add a new Name" label?

Comment: open: function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").find("a").last().attr('href','http://www.google.com').addClass('highLight');
    }

Comment: i am doing the same thing ,but i want to add it should display in the first position . IS there any way to access the index.Thanks.